# Nested functions in "class"

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function Fruits() {

    this.Banana = function() {

        this.getColor = function(){
            return 'yellow';
        };

    };

    this.Apple= function() {

        this.getColor = function(){
            return 'red';
        };

    };
}

var apple = new Fruits.Apple();
console.log(apple.getColor());
```

This doesnt work. What did i miss here? Is this the wrong approach on a "class" with nested methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some curiosity:

```
var a = new new Fruits().Apple
```

Btw. Maybe you wanted to create a something like static class?

```
var Fruits = {
    Apple:function() {

        this.getColor = function(){
            return 'red';
        };

    },
    Banana: function() {

        this.getColor = function(){
            return 'yellow';
        };
    }
}
```

Then it would work.

```
var apple = new Fruits.Apple();
console.log(apple.getColor());
```

Comment: Yes, this will be perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
var apple = new Fruits();
apple.Apple();
console.log(apple.getColor());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate Fruits first.  From my console...

```
var f = new Fruits()
undefined
new f.Apple()
Fruits.Apple
new f.Apple().getColor()
"red"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the very difference between static properties and instance properties.
As you declared Apple as an instance property of Fruits, you have to instanciate a Fruit to be allowed to instanciate an apple, and the cronstructor of Apple will be a method of Fruit.
If you want static class you have to do

```
function Fruits() {
```

};
   Fruits.Apple= function() {

```
    this.getColor = function(){
        return 'red';
    };

};
```